# Is it possible to get the SystemItem of a UIBarButtonItem in Swift?

Tags: swift, uikit, uibarbuttonitem

I have a bunch of `UIBarButtonItem`s in a `UIToolbar`. Each of which has its `SystemItem` set in Storyboard, so that they'll look like system icons.

I'd rather not make an `IBAction` for each and every one of them, so I need some way to differentiate them in a switch statement. I am assuming the best way to do this is by looking at their `SystemItem`, since that's the only property that makes them unique from one another.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let controller = UIImagePickerController()
    controller.delegate = self

    switch sender.[WHAT DO I PUT HERE?] {
    case .compose:
        controller.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    case .camera:
        controller.sourceType = .camera
    default:
        break
    }

    present(controller, animated: true)
}
```

If there is a better way to differentiate between `UIBarButtonItem`s, I'm all ears.

Comment: using .tag property is the best practice

Comment: Did you get a solution for this question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
switch sender.tag {
case 0 :
    controller.sourceType = .photoLibrary
case 1 :
    controller.sourceType = .camera
default:
    break
}
```

and set a different tag for each button

Comment: In case it's not obvious to others, you first need to set the tag of each button. And it's always best to avoid using a tag value of `0` since that is the default tag.